# can I show coming notification always on top of status abr

Tags: android

can I show coming notification always on top of all other notification . in new version lollipop it is default...but what to do for others previous versions .i am using Samsung note 2 device.

Comment: do you mean a persistent notification that cannot be removed or displaying actual text on the statusbar?

Comment: i mean ,if two notification already exist on status bar then third always come on above of two ........not below ... please help

Answer (score 0):

In order to put it there you have to add a flag to the LayoutParams
of your WindowManager and after that add the NotificationView.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);

mWindowManager.addView(mHeadsUpNotificationView, lp);
```

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODALWindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
Try adding all of these flags with "|" to the one that you are using